# I want to get battery stats of usage of every hour of 24 hour. how can it get it?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, battery

I have implemented workmanager , alarm manager and job scheduler also to get the battery level after every hour. but most of the android mobiles devices restrict the all of them to work continuesly . I am facing problem in this please help?

Comment: @Enowneb i have implemented periodic workmanger for getting battery level after every hour . it is woking fine until i am using the app but when device got idle . it is not working fine . And i am missing the values of hours battery level

Comment: Is it possible to provide your code attempt? Not sure if it is code related or else. *Hint: You can edit your question and post your code there.*

Comment: var periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker2>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
   .build()
 val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
 workManager.enqueue(
            periodicWorkRequest
        )

Comment: this is priodice work that i am using to call for every hour to execute